# Use of sqlite3_stmt in sqlite3?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm new to to iOS and sqlite3 and I found little confused in the way `sqlite3_stmt`is used in ios4 can someone explain why and how sqlite3_stmt should be used in ios development??

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html)? If yes, what part did you not understand?

Comment: This question is utterly incomprehensible.